# Alternative to spring profiles

Tags: spring

Using spring 3 I can determine which bean to use at runtime. But using Spring 2.5 what is the alternative?

Here is the config within my context file :

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/mydb"
        resource-ref="true" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

I can use a profile to determine whether or not to use this datasource, what is the alternative when using an earlier version of spring (earlier than Spring 3)

Update :

"myDataSource" will be injected when I run my app locally, on a prod environment the "jndi" lookup, will be used. To inject "myDataSource" using Spring 3 I can use "profiles" but what alternative can I use if not using Spring 3 ?

Comment: 1) But I expect that some bean will have "myDataSource" injcted. So do you really want to "remove" the "myDataSource" bean in some situations or just have an other configuration? 2) is this other configuration the test environment?

Comment: @Ralph please see question update, I just want to inject an alternative datasource, by configurations do you mean, test/prod environments ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define all your environment depend beans into several files, such as :

- `beans-dev.xml`
- `beans-prod.xml`

Your XML config would be :

```
<beans>

<import resource="beans-${myapp.env}.xml"/>

<bean id="bean1" class="..."/>
<bean id="bean2" class="..."/>

</beans>
```

In this case, `myapp.env` property is a JVM system property, i.e. configured with `-Dmyapp.env=dev` or `-Dmyapp.env=prod`. `myapp.env` cannot be setted from a property placeholder since Spring `<import>` are resolved *before* property placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build out this kind of thing yourself.  Typically by maintaining a number of different files for each profile that get composed together and a convention for picking the correct file at runtime.  A -D System Property can help you pick which one.  For example, we could have applicationContext-dev.xml and applicationContext-prod.xml, our applicationContext.xml would import applicationContext-${activeProfile}.xml, and you can set and load -DactiveProfile=dev; you can infer some of the other conventions like a context-param in the web.xml, etc. from how Spring3 profiles are designed.