# Is Spring's @Profile on methods a good practice

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have a Spring Boot Web application exposing rest services.

I'm asking myself how to correctly manage profiles on Filters.
Actually, my app has 2 profiles: dev and prod (you guess what it stands for...)

In prod mode, i have more filters to activate than in dev mode.

My Filters configuration class is the following:

```
@Configuration
public class FiltersConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean(CompositeFilter compositeFilter){
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
        filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(compositeFilter);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public CompositeFilter devCompositeFilter(){
        CompositeFilter compositeFilter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filtersList = new ArrayList<>();
        //filtersList.add(filter1());
        compositeFilter.setFilters(filtersList);
        return compositeFilter;
    }


    @Bean
    @Profile("prod")
    public CompositeFilter prodCompositeFilter(){
        CompositeFilter compositeFilter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filtersList = new ArrayList<>();
        //filtersList.add(filter1());
        compositeFilter.setFilters(filtersList);
        return compositeFilter;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Is it a good practice to add @Profile on method?
- Is there a way to force the compiler to exclude classes, methods, etc. annotated   with a diferent profiles than the one set as current?
  (I don't want my production jar/war populated with unnecessary code!)
- Does spring boot provide a clearer way to organize profiles?

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better to have configurations for different environments in distinct packages. You don't want to mix your configuration. 
The structure might look like this:

```
config
    - Config1.java
    - Config2.java
    dev
        - WebConfig.java
        - DataConfig.java
    prod
        - WebConfig.java
        - DataConfig.java
```

Comment: How does this fit in with Spring Boot's ecosystem?

Answer (score 6):

In my own experience, using `@Profile` in any java code is not a good idea. This is why I think you have to avoid using it in the code:

1. You can always define property like `my.feature-for-the-profile.enabled` to achieve the same goal by using profile.
2. Profiles diverge sometimes, keep every changing configuration as properties give you more control on everything, everywhere.
3. Spring Boot has a well defined profile-specific externalize properties support (like application-`prod`.yml). Having profile in you code base will make things more complicated and sometimes *misleading*.
4. You can modify or override by using properties more easily than update and recompiling your code.
5. `ProfileCondition` (as meta-annotation on `@Profile`) is not a `SpringBootCondition`, you can not use `/autoconfig` to determine is it activated or not.

The bottom line: Define profiles for `properties`, not for `@Configuration`s nor `@Bean`s.

If you really want to exclude test stuff for your production code, take a look on the documentation of [spring-boot-devtools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html), if your using Maven, you can put all test classes/resources in a separate module, and mark its as `<optional>true</optional>` or define maven profile for it. Notice, having maven profile and spring boot profile at the same time maybe confusing!

Comment: My experience also led me to the same conclusion. Defining a property for each feature instead of using @Profile makes the code more readable and gives you more flexibility to mix and match features in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good practice to add @Profile on method?

It is the spring approach to this problem - so it is in keeping with the spring ecosystem

> Is there a way to force the compiler to exclude classes, methods, etc. annotated with a diferent profiles than the one set as current? (I don't want my production jar/war populated with unnecessary code!)

You would have to tune your build to exclude classes - another approach is to configure the beans with id's, and use the ID's and configuration per environment. An approach similar to [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407601/alternative-to-spring-profiles)

In my experience Profiles are easier

> Does spring boot provide a clearer way to organize profiles?

Not that I know of, except the approach in the link above

Comment: If i tune my build to exclude class, that means that i have @Profile set on the class and not on the method right?  Because if on the same class i have two methods annotated with different profile, i guess both methods will be compiled in the .class file regardless of the profile used at compile time!  Tha's exactly what is confusing for me.

Comment: Or use some kind of build process filtering - i guess that would move a profile concept into your build process