# Change method based on environment

Tags: java, spring

How can I switch between two method calls of the same name based on the environment?

I know that this can be done at the class level with `@Profile`, but is there a way to do this at the method level? So ideally, I would want something like the below snippet.

**Example**

```
public class Foo {

    @Profile('local')
    public void bar() {...}

    @Profile('prod')
    public void bar() {...}
```

Comment: There isn't. Just create 2 instances of a bean, put an interface in front of it and use 1 of the 2 implementations based on the `@Profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spring 4.x is possible newly to control the profile directly with annotating by [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) on the method level.

> ... as a method-level annotation on any `@Bean` method

Personally, I do not use profiles on the method level, read more at [Is Spring's @Profile on methods a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920369/is-springs-profile-on-methods-a-good-practice)

---

In your case, I rather suggest you the following approach:

Create two classes and make the implement the common interface.

```
public interface Foo {
    public void bar();
}
```

Annotate each with `@Profile` based on the environment.

```
@Component
@Profile("local")
public class LocalFoo implements Foo {

    @Override
    public void bar() { ... }
}

@Component
@Profile("prod")
public class ProdFoo implements Foo {

    @Override
    public void bar() { ... }
}
```

Since now, they are ready to be injected according to the active profile.